# Having trouble getting eshell remote shell multi-hop to work

Tags: tramp, eshell, ssh

I can get single hop ssh to work just fine:

```
~ $ cd /ssh:cpatti@wak-prod-jump1:~
/ssh:cpatti@wak-prod-jump1:/home/jumpboxaccess_emergency $
```

But when I try multi-hop, I get command not found every time:

```
cd /ssh:cpatti@wak-prod-jump1|ssh:root@wak-prod-knife:~
ssh:root@wak-prod-knife:~: command not found
```

I'm running emacs 25.0.50.1 on OSX Yosemite in case that matters.

Comment: The pipe `|` is special to the shell, try quoting the whole filename.

Comment: @politza Hey make this into an answer so I can mark it answered! :) That worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipe `|` is special to the shell, try quoting the whole filename.